# TypeScript - passing a fieldname of an interface in a type-safe manner

Tags: typescript

I have:

```
interface MyInterface {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}
```

I have another general-purpose function:

```
myFunction(myInstance: MyInterace, fieldName: string) {
   let field = myInstance[fieldName];

   // do something with this field
}
```

Usage being:

```
myFunction(myInst, "a");
or
myFunction(myInst, "b");
```

However, I would like to pass "a" or "b" in a type-safe manner. That means that if I were to change MyInterace a field to a2, the call used in myFunction(myInst, "a") wouldn't compile and I would be able to find in compilation time all these places that got broken due to renaming.

I tried using Pick but couldn't get the name of the field from it.

Any suggestions?
I would imagine that there should be some:

```
MyInterace::a from which I could extra the string "a".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to declare `fieldName` as type `keyof MyInterface`

```
function myFunction(myInstance: MyInterface, fieldName: keyof MyInterface) {
   let field = myInstance[fieldName];
   // do something with this field
}

myFunction({ a: 'a', b: 1 }, 'a')
myFunction({ a: 'a', b: 1 }, 'b')
myFunction({ a: 'a', b: 1 }, 'c') // type error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlTk4AuZAZzClAHMBuEsgIypAFcBbN6FgF8iRGFxAIwwAPYhkPdADFxkmSAAUC7LTgSIVDNkixEEADTIYwCABsAJgDk4PfcgDWEdNJhosOE0gAlISsyDYQYJbW9sgAvPJ+OnoA2la2js4QALosoQD0ech20jTSLmAAFozIAO7AlciVwNRR6UTCRArKElKy6gTkVADkcEMWHMgAjMiCFiNDgZ1KKr0aA5TI8+NU07ObbAtL3ap968Oj21MzcwgLyAWN6AAOKNBQ0lBAA)

---

Or as a fancier version, you can make this generic and then it will work with any type, and not just `MyInterface`.

Now you pass any type to `myInstance`, and `fieldName` is required to be a `keyof` whatever that type is.

```
function myFunctionGeneric<T>(myInstance: T, fieldName: keyof T) {
  let field = myInstance[fieldName];
  // do something with this field
}

myFunctionGeneric({ foo: 'a', bar: 1 }, 'foo')
myFunctionGeneric({ foo: 'a', bar: 1 }, 'bing') // type error
```

Of course only use this generic version if you need to, since it introduces complexity for something you might not need at all.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlTk4AuZAZzClAHMBuEsgIypAFcBbN6FgF8iRGFxAIwwAPYhkPdADFxkmSADiEENGAIAPABUAfAAoF2WnAkQqBgDTIYwCABsAJgDk4PG8gDWEOjSMMgGAJSErC4QYI7O7sgAvPJYIJbWANpOrp7eEAC6LKQA9MXIbtI00j5gABaMyADuwHXIdcDUcTlEwkQKyhJSspra9AgmBI7S0lQA5HCzDmxwUFQAjMiCDrMw07NhfUoqQxpaOuOTuzPI84vIy6vIG1s3bIz7yKVt6AAOKNBQaRQERAA)